# req.flash() data persists even after refreshing the page using connect-flash

Tags: node.js, sails.js, connect-flash

I am using connect-flash to have a flash message in my sailjs app. The flash message persists even after refreshing the page. I tried the solution on [this](https://github.com/expressjs/flash/issues/1)

I created a policy to clear the `req.session.flash` array before any request but doing that shows no flash message any time. What's the correct way to show the flash message only once?

Edit :-

Code in my policy :-

```
        //removeFlash.js
        module.exports = async function(req, res, next) {
            req.session.flash = {};
            next();
        };
```

policies.js contains

`'*' : 'removeFlash'`

My controller contains

`req.flash("error_msg", "Incorrect username or password.");
 return res.redirect("/login");`

Comment: Could you share the code in question, I know the solution in the link works but it might not work depending on how you handle the response in your code.

Comment: @OlliK I've added the code.